# Selenium test : (junit.framework.TestSuite$1)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I'm trying to perform selenium test with :
Selenium IDE 2.9 and export my test as Java / Junit 4 RC as it

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Search {
    private Selenium selenium;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "https://www.google.fr/");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSearch() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.type("id=lst-ib", "selenium");
        selenium.click("name=btnG");
        selenium.click("link=Selenium - Web Browser Automation");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Then i compile it, yet when i launch the test i've got an error

```
There was 1 failure:
1) warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No
tests found in Search

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1,  Errors: 0
```

As far as i understood i should edit my .java file then recompile it.

But i'm not sure what should i edit, can anyone give me an example.

Thx

Comment: How do your run your test? Ant, Maven, ...

Comment: Neither and nor maven.
Just export my test as .java file then i compile it.
For info i'm using junit-4.10 and selenium-java-2.48.2

Comment: Do you run it from the command-line or from the IDE?

Comment: From the command line javac -cp ...
After some research it seems that using Firefox IDE is not such a good way of working and even this is disconcerting for non-developer i installed Eclipse, TestNG and trying to perform my test, so far so good.
( i think @StefanBirkner has right by the way )

Answer (score 0):

Your tests are JUnit 4 tests but it looks like you're running them as JUnit 3 test (because of `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError`).